# Workout in the morning

Tags: workout, gym, sports

I'm going to start going to the gym before work which is going at 7AM. My question is when do i have my breakfast?

Before or after the GYM and if before the GYM how much time do i need to process the food And if after do i finish working out and directly eat or wait?

Thanks

Comment: That's completely up to you. We don't all react in the same way. Some people will prefer one over the other. Try it out and find what works for you.

Comment: I dont know what is the right way for the body. in terms of power, i need food to get energy and to be able to workout. But i don't know, if i have breakfast i can't just go and start my workout i need to wait for atleast 2 hrss

Comment: What do you mean you have to wait for at least two hours? What's stopping you?

Comment: digest the food..

Comment: Yes, but what's stopping you from working out while digesting the food?

Comment: how can someone workout after a meal? it's not good. your stomach is digesting everything and you are moving around and lifting.

Comment: That depends on what you eat, and how much. I usually have a pre-workout meal, then go to the gym within 15 minutes. Sounds to me like you're eating something your stomach can't handle.

Comment: Normal breakfast, boiled egg, orange juice , water etc..

Comment: Well it's simple then. If you can't workout after that meal, workout before it. You just answered your own question.

Comment: But is it effective if you workout on an empty stomach?

Comment: That's different from person to person. Only you can find out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wake up at 5, eat a bowl of oats and a couple hard-boiled eggs, drink a creatine/citrulline-malate shake on my way to the gym, lift, and start work at 7. It isn't ideal, but your body will adapt to whatever schedule your life forces you to live because of work/school. The important thing is that you get in there!

Comment: When I used to train in the mornings, I'd get up, have a strong black coffee and a banana and head straight to the gym, then eat a decent breakfast afterwards at my desk. I agree that your body will adapt to whatever you force it to :)